# Best (fastest) way to remove mirror image data points in R?

Tags: database, r, subset, standard-deviation

I'm filtering large data sets of mirror image points; data points that are equal in magnitude but opposite in sign. These mirror image pairs tend to be v. large and skew the standard deviation. My code works [i.e. it removes mirror image payment pairs], but takes hours to run. Is there a better way to do this in R?

Here's the code:

```
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
    for(j in 1:length(data)) {
        if (data[i] < 0){
            if (abs(data[i]) == abs(data[j])){
                mirrors = rbind(mirrors, c(data[i], data[j]))
                break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

data is the large set of payment claims, approx. 200,000 items.

(I know, I know, for loops are blasphemy in R but I couldn't figure out another way to do it.)

Comment: Is `data` a vector? and does the order of the values matter? (if it were sorted would that be an issue)? So you want to remove *any* occurence of a value `x` from the data where the value `-x` is also in the data? i.e. `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, -1, -4)` --> `c(2, 3, 5)`? (note here `-1` appears twice but `1` appears just once and I've removed them all)

Comment: Thanks for the looking into this!
`data` is a vector. Order does matter, although I could include an identifying number w/in `data` so that it has two columns.

I only want to remove the first occurrence of mirror pairs (`x`  and `-x`). The "break" in the second for loop is for this purpose.

Comment: It would help for you to put in a few example input/outputs showing what you want to happen for multiple cases (multiple pairs of duplicates, unbalanced duplicates, different orderings, etc). Also, in your code you produce a matrix (?) `mirrors`, but in your comments to answers you are talking about the reduced `data` but have not explained what form it takes (remove negative duplicate and retain positive? so `-1, 2, -3, 1, -1, 1, 2` --> `2, -3, 1, -1, 1, 2`? (here I've only identified the first (-1, 1) as a duplicate and removed just the -1, and left the second (-1, 1))

Answer (score 0):

As @mathematical.coffee indicates, the answer depends on whether you will remove or reduce mirrored values. Assuming that mirrored values are exchangeable:

```
M <- c(1:10, -(1:10), 11:25)

## remove all but one set of mirrored duplicates
M[!duplicated(abs(M))] # retains whatever set of mirrored duplicates comes first, positive or negative
unique(abs(M)) # retains positive half of mirrored duplicates

## remove all mirrored duplicate pairs (or triplets, or quadruplets, or...)
d <- which(duplicated(abs(M), fromLast = T) | duplicated(abs(M))) # any duplicated value
M[-d]
```

Comment: Ahh yes duplicated.. Played around w/ that function for awhile and couldn't figure it out. This is super helpful! 
So `d` will be equal to `M` but w/out ANY mirrors? i.e. if `M` includes the values -1, 1, 1, then all three of these are removed? 

Is there an easy way to only remove the first occurrence of mirror image pairs? Similar to what `break` does in the second for loop? So `M` should still include the value 1, but -1 and 1 are removed.

Comment: In my example, `d` are the indices of duplicate pairs/triplets/whatever. So `M[-d]` drops all duplicates. To retain the last duplicate: `M[!duplicated(abs(M), fromLast = T)]`. To see this: `M <- c(-1,1,1); M[!duplicated(abs(M), fromLast = T)]`. The argument `fromLast` controls whether duplicates are flagged relative to values occurring first, or values occurring last. Otherwise, this is identical to the first example I gave.

Comment: This is better, but it still doesn't work. Positive repeated values should be kept, in this method they are removed. For example, `M = c(1:10,1:10,11:25)` should not be affected, but `M[!duplicated(abs(M), fromLast = T)]' returns `M = c(1:10, 11:25)`


I'll try to tweak it, but if you have any additional suggestions it would be seriously appreciated.

Comment: `remNegDup <- function(M) M[!((duplicated(abs(M)) & M < 0) | (duplicated(abs(M), fromLast = T) & M < 0))]`. Then, for your example: `M1 = c(1:10,1:10,11:25); remNegDup(M1)`. To verify that this deletes negative duplicates: `M2 = c(1:10,1:10,-(1:10),11:25); remNegDup(M2)`. To verify that this retains negatives which are not duplicates: `M3 = c(1:10,1:10,-(1:10),11:25,-(17:38)); remNegDup(M3)`